# Print list while excluding specific named values

Tags: python, list

I am looking for a basic way to exclude printing an item from a list (not remove/delete) if that named value = something specified, e.g. = 0

I thought it would be something basic like this, but I get an error that I is not defined.

```
a = 2
b = 0
c = 4
d = 0
e = 6

lis = [a,b,c,d,e]

while i != 0 in range(lis):
  print (lis[i])
```

Wanted result:
2
4
6

Seems like I am missing something simple? Or is this not as simple as I imagined?

Comment: Do you want to do something like `for i in range(lis): if i!=0 : print i`?

Comment: There's no `while [condition] in [collection]` syntax in Python. There is `for [var] in [collection]` though.

Comment: this gives
"TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list"

Comment: Python requires you to iterate and check your results in separate steps. Iterate over the values first then implement your check next in the body of that loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python syntax doesn't support a conditional where you're trying to apply it. There are several alternatives, though:

You could put the condition inside the loop:

```
for item in lis:
    if item != 0:
        print item
```

You could filter the list:

```
for item in filter(lambda i: i!=0, lis):  # filter(None, lis) works too
    print item
```

Or using a list comprehension (technically a *generator expression* here):

```
for item in (i for i in lis if i != 0):
    print item
```

Or skip the loop entirely:

```
print '\n'.join(str(i) for i in lis if i != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for l in lis:
    if l != 0:
        print l
```

Iterate through the items in the list one by one. Every time, check the current item `l` to see if it equals 0. Print the item if it is non-zero.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the options which you can use.

1) You can use either a **normal loop**

```
for i in lis:
    if i != 0:
        print i
```

**OR**

2) **List Comprehensions**

```
[i for i in lis if i!=0]
```

I would still say when coming to Stackoverflow, please consider going  through the tutorials, because its the most basic thing in python.